# Phrasing of sentence help please

Tags: phrasing

This is a property that restricts her ability to respond to emotions other than sadness.

Does this mean that she can only respond to sadness?
Thank you.

Comment: This site is not a substitute for having a friend to practice Engish with. You need to show evidence that you have tried to answer it yourself.

Comment: I phrased the sentence myself. I wanted to ascertain that it meant what I wanted it to mean.

Comment: You should be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RL36 What difference does that make? As I said, this site is not a substitute for praticing with a friend.

Comment: @curiousdannii Well I do apologize. I browsed through some of the questions asked here, and was mislead to thinking these questions were appropriate. Apologies once again.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't necessarily mean that she *can't* respond to other emotions, but that her responses to those emotions are limited or weakened.

Answer (score -1):

Basically yes, but I'm more concerned with the usage of "property."

"Property" isn't much used about persons, except for things they own, say a piece of land:-)

I find it quite cold.

I might think about a "personal feature" or "character trait" or "personal characteristic."

Comment: You still shouldn't be answering off topic questions. And you still need to vote more.

Comment: Is this why you don't have too many answers? Everything's off topic?

Comment: Only 1% of questions on this site should have even been asked. Finding a good question which I can answer is extremely rare.